# Can I identify gmail notification for new mail from my android application

Tags: android, gmail

Can i identify notifications and get the details of the notifications from my android application? if so,can any one help me please...

Answer (score 1):

You got no access to what notifications are currently posted. App could do some broadcasting on events that may interest others but I doubt GMail app does so, so answer is rather "no".